# SQL Search column for each variable in CSV string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a variable passed to stored procedure 
Ex:

```
@keywords = 'val1, val3, val5'
```

And i'm trying to see if column named Title contain any of them in it

```
Ex: Title1 - 'Hello val1'
    Title2 - 'Hello val3'   
    Title3 - 'Hello val1, val3'  
    Title4 - 'Hello'
```

SO my results should return values

```
Title
------
Hello val1
Hello val3
Hello val1, val3
```

Is this possible to use LIKE or any other function/method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split the CSV into rows (see [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005 and Beyond](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) for variuos techniques how). I'll assume that you create `dbo.ufnSplitRows` based on this

Then JOIN using LIKE

```
SELECT *
FROM
    MYtable M
    JOIN
    dbo.ufnSplitRows (@CSV) C ON M.Title LIKE '%' + C.SplitValue + '%'
```

By the way, it will run poorly because of the leading '%' at least

Comment: what is this dbo.ufnSplitRows?

Comment: @GirishKG: a generic name for some user split function in SQL Server. There are several available on Google, here on SO, or in the link I sent

Answer (score 2):

If you make some assumptions about how the query string is stored, then yes (though it's not terribly efficient):

Assumption: the string will be stored with every item separated by a comma, then a space. (This is what you posted in your question)

```
select * from YourTable where 
    (@keywords like KeyColumn + ', %') or
    (@keywords like '%, ' + KeyColumn + ', %') or
    (@keywords like '%, ' + KeyColumn)
```

Comment: You'd need leading % too + start/end of string conditions

Comment: @gbn: Thanks; I had already started correcting right after I posted it.

Comment: yep, now it's as ugly as I expected :-)

Comment: I guess this will not work for my case. I want to search each word in @keyword in keycolumn

Comment: @rs: have you tried this? It should work too. It's just less clear in my opinion but this does not mean it doesn't work.

Comment: @gbn: Agreed, it's ugly. The only advantage is being self-contained; you don't have to create a table-valued function (there are myriad string-splitting function scripts available).

Comment: I tried it didn't work will this work for string 'Hello val1 how are you doing?'