# stored procedure csv input

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split Function equivalent in tsql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql)
>   [SQL Search column for each variable in CSV string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160719/sql-search-column-for-each-variable-in-csv-string)

I have a stored procedure which takes input `@Notifications` as `34181,34182,34184` etc, a string.

Now, I want to split this string in such a way that another variable `@Notification` will contain first time `34181` and next time `34182` etc.

These numbers `34181` length is not fixed. It can be `341812` or just `3` also because of this I cannot use substr function.

How can I split this string?

Comment: Top right, search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+%2Bsplit. You have have never voted and never accepted any answers.

Comment: Check out the following thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

you can use function `charIndex` with combination of substring function. e.g.

```
select Phone,charindex('-',Phone) from customers

Result

030-0074321    4
```

http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2008/05/instr-function-in-sql-server.html

Comment: You can't for repeated values...

Comment: My approach would be

get index of first comma, and get value from zero index to comma index, that will be my first value. Now take substring from original String such that Originial String = (commaIndex + 1, Originial String Length)....Now again finad index of comma....

Comment: @gbn I guess it should work, I dont know of some better String function to achieve this goal, although i will search

Comment: I am trying to Contains function to search comma but it throws an error incorrect syntax

Comment: I have used charindex and its working thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While you already have many links on how to create a `string.Split` function in SQL, a simple way for this is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE ',' + @CustomerID + ',' LIKE '%,' + Customers.CustomerID + ',%'
```

While it will not use any index on Customer ID, if you only have a small table this is fine, otherwise duplicate the `string.split` method in a function and call that.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.Split(@CustomerIDs, ','))
```

Or very similar to that.